# Upload multiple images to azure from windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, image-uploading

Is it possible to upload multiple images(In my case 4) to azure blob storage from windows phone 8 app.I am using Windows Azure storage library,Im able to upload a single image.Is there an option to upload multiple images?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution would be to create a Web API service that you would call from your Windows Phone 8 application and send the picture to the Web API that would handle uploading your picture to a blob storage.

Comment: Thank you.. Dont you think it is more time consuming like sending it from phone to web service and web service to azure?

Comment: I agree but that is a recommended approach for Windows Phone 8 apps. If you would like to communicate with an external database (in this case with a blob storage) then use Web API or some other web service technology. You could also take advantage of the mobile services: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/